# runtime const value set for arr size and no error

Tags: c, constants

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func()
{
    int a = 3, b = 4;
    int c = a * b;
    return c;
}

int main()
{
    const int N = 10;
    int arr[N];
    printf("size = %ld\n", sizeof(arr));

    int x = 10;
    const int SIZE = x;
    int buf[SIZE];
    printf("size = %ld\n", sizeof(buf));
    
    const int FN = func();
    int buf2[FN];
    printf("size = %ld\n", sizeof(buf2));

    return 0;
}
```

ubuntu 20 5.4.0-42-generic
gcc 9.3.0

compile:

```
gcc const_create_arr.c -Wall
```

show no warning

output:

```
size = 40
size = 40
size = 48
```

output corret

the last one FN is init by func(). we know that func() return vlaue should be computed in runtime. But an array definition should provide the true length of this array to compiler to help compiler allocate space. So I think the last one should not be passed at compiling. But it seems corret. I want to know how it works. Whether my gcc has optimise it and compute the func return when it compiling.

Answer (score 1):

C has variable length arrays, so `int x[y]` is valid C provided `y` is defined in advance. It doesn't matter if `y` is `const` or not, it just needs to be `> 0` to make any sense, as well as small enough that you don't use up the entire stack.

In this case `y` is `12`, so you get a length 48 (`12 * sizeof(int)` where that's `4`). This gets computed after the fact, not in advance like you might expect for something trivial like `sizeof(int)`.

In C++ this is not the case as defined by the standard, however some compilers will still do it the C way.

Comment: so c support this feature and compiler still set up array at runtime not in compiling?

Comment: Re “it just needs to be >= 0”: The size must be greater than zero. C 2018 6.7.6.2 5 says “ If the size is an expression that is not an integer constant expression: … each time it is evaluated it shall have a value greater than zero.”

Answer (score 1):

In all three cases you're creating a **variable length array**.  For an array to *not* be a VLA the size needs to be an *integer constant expression*, and a variable with the `const` qualifier (no matter how it's initialized) does not qualify as one.

The definition of a VLA can be found in section 6.7.6.2p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding array declarators:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type.  If the size is `*` instead of being  an  expression,  the  array  type  is  a *variable  length  array* type  of  unspecified  size, which can only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype scope; such arrays are nonetheless complete types.  **If the size is an integer constant expression and  the  element  type  has  a  known  constant  size,  the  array  type  is  not  a  variable  length array  type;  otherwise,  the  array  type  is  a variable  length  array type.**

And the definition of an integer constant expression is given in section 6.6p6:

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and  shall  only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants,   enumeration   constants,   character   constants, `sizeof` expressions  whose  results  are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and  floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast operators in an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator.

There is nothing in this definition that qualifies a `const` qualified variable as an integer constant expression, so the `sizeof` operator in each of the three cases is being evaluated at runtime because the arrays are VLAs.

Comment: constexpr is the feature of c++11

Comment: @MelvinLevett You're using C, not C++.

Comment: I remember when I in university, an array in c must specify its size when compiling.

Comment: @MelvinLevett VLAs were added to the C99 standard, then made optional in C11.

Comment: But I think my first and second both are constant expression. So you said both of my three cases are VLA. I disaggree. sorry I think in c++11. I am wrong.

Comment: @MelvinLevett See my edit with relevant quotes from the standard.